# non-reacting import in eclipse

Tags: java, import

I'm working on a java project and i'm using Timer class. So, I imported `javax.swing.*`. However, when I want to create new Timer object, it behaves as having no imported timer package. But when I import it as `javax.swing.Timer` , it recognizes and I can use it. Is it a compiler's bug or don't I know what `.*` works? Thanks...

Comment: It works fine with `import javax.swing.*;` also.

Comment: It didn't work on my eclipse at first time even I save and refresh it again. I assume that compiler doesn't search all packages immediately. Now i tried to put `*` and it works..

Answer (score 0):

I am typing this as an answer as this would exceed comment character limit.

First off, "it behaves as having no imported timer package." - there is no such thing as a timer package. `javax.swing.Timer` is a class

Importing like `import javax.swing.*` should make `javax.swing.Timer` available for your class in eclipse's editor. However, if eclipse is forcing you to make declarations like `javax.swing.Timer timer = ..` even though you have `import javax.swing.*;` at the top, it is very likely that you have imported a different kind of timer. Look through your import statement and look for the likes of `import java.util.Timer` that can cause this behavior. Also, certain syntax errors in previous lines can cause this behavior. All in all, your question will get appropriate answer if you write your question appropriately. You need provide at least glimpses of your code as to what you are doing so that people who totally do not see your screen will have some idea what we are talking about.